# Add homogeneous coordinate (x0=1) to images in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, image-processing, computer-vision

I have 7 images of size 29*29, I want to add one homogenous coordinate (augment them 
with feature, x0=1) to all 7 images, but I am not sure how to do it.

my original image dimension is

```
images.shape 
#(7, 29, 29)
```

**What I have tried** is zipping np.ones() but it ends up making separate array for first feature resulting in dimension 7*2

```
np.array([list(a) for a in zip(np.ones([7,1]),images_all[:,:])]).shape
#(7,2)
#
#[[array([1.]),
# array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
      0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
     [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
      0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
 ....
```

As you can see, it adds 1 as separate array and does append in as the first element.

Also, I tried to loop through images and insert 1 at the first element, but it makes dimension 30 and gives error

```
for i in range(len(images)):
    images[i][0] = np.insert(images[i][0], 0, 1., axis=0)
```

> ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (30) into shape (29)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create a larger array of ones, reshape the original array and update the larger array.

```
padded_images = np.ones((7,29*29+1))
padded_images[:,1:] = images.reshape(7,29*29)
```

Comment: It will add 30 ones in each image, As per my understanding, it should add only 1 one in each?(not sure). Also, you are pushing it on last not as first(prepend)?

Comment: @A.B What output shape do you want?

Comment: if possible,   (7,  842) will work, since 29*29=841, but having pushed 1 as first element for each , it will make it 842

Comment: thanks, got it :) how can i learn these things(dimension manipulation,reindexing, reshaping etc)

Comment: @A.B Check this out- http://cs231n.github.io/python-numpy-tutorial/#numpy-array-indexing